# How to determine Probability of a 4 and 6 sided die.

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

A fair four-sided die and a fair six-sided die are rolled. Write down the sample space of all possible outcomes. (Fairness means all these simple outcomes have the same probability of occurrence.) Let A denote the sum of the numbers on the top faces is ≥ 14. Let B be the event that the sum of the numbers on the top faces is ≤ 16. Are the events A and B mutually exclusive?

I have the first part
There are 24 possible outcomes.

S=  (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)
    (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)
    (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
    (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)
(5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4)
(6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4)

but the second part of this question is really getting to me, I don't believe i am thinking of it the right way. If i denote A to be the sum of the numbers on the top faces is ≥ 14 then its 0, because the highest roll you can do with those two dice are a 4 and a 6. I know I must be thinking this the wrong way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is checking that you understand mutually exclusive, which means the two events cannot both happen. If one cannot happen, then both cannot, so they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you've copied the question down correctly here, I don't think you're thinking of anything wrong; the question appears to be trivial (i.e. have an uninteresting answer). One of two things appears to be the case:

Option 1: Either you've mis-copied a problem, or there's a misprint in the problem text, or something like that. (Best guess -- did you mean *product* instead of *sum* to define these events?)

Option 2: Maybe the instructor / text / whatever intended for you to think through a trivial event. As written, you're right; the probability of event $A$ is $0$.